# Regular Expression to parse Class declaration line in Java

Tags: java, regex

Need to parse a Class declaration line in Java using regular expression e.g.

```
String line = "public class ActionDiagramReader extends XReader implements ActionHandler, Action {";
String line  = "public class ActionDiagramReader extends XReader{";
```

I am trying to use this regex

```
String regExp = ".*class\\s+(\\w+)(\\s+extends\\s+(\\w+))?(\\s+implements\\s+(\\w|,)+)?\\{.*$";
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(regExp, Pattern.DOTALL | Pattern.CASE_INSENSITIVE | Pattern.MULTILINE);
Matcher match = pattern.matcher(line1);
```

But this regex fails to parse classname/extender classname/implementer clas-name. Need to just identify all the classes & interfaces associated with given lines.

What is incorrect in my regular expression. 
Thanks in advance

Comment: Need to color the class names on Eclipse editor in a application

Comment: Can you not use something like (?<=public class\s).*?(?=\s) and (?<=extends\s).*?(?=[\s{])        Just a thought

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The last part in your regex isn't grabbing the action.

```
(\\s+implements\\s+(\\w|,)+)?\\{.*$
```

It grabs up to ActionHandler, then dies because it's looking for curly brace next.
It my example below, I put the final \w into square braces and added \s to also capture any spaces, this way it will capture the "Action" at the end of the line as well.

```
(\\s+implements\\s+([\\w,\\s]+))?\\s*\\{.*$
```

See if that works for you.

Comment: That won't work: A pipe in square brackets is escaped and so "implements Piped|Interface" is incorrectly accepted.

Comment: Ahh, thanks. I didn't catch it because it actually succeeded in my test, although it shouldn't be there. That was my best interpretation of what was asked.

Answer (score 0):

You're not explaining your error messages so there might be more, but I see one issue: For the inheritance capture, you are capturing many groups of one character.

You should use `([\\w,]+)` in that area to get the list of implemented interfaces. Otherwise I suggest using this to get each one individually: `(\\w+)(?:,\\s*(\\w+))*`

I think there may be other subtle bugs, though. It depends on what you are seeing and what you are expecting to see.

Comment: Now I tested the same regex on this line `String line1 = "public class ActionDiagramReader extends XReader implements ActionHandler, ActionHandler1, Action, Action1{";`. But it fails to identify all implementer classes.

Comment: What *does* it identify? Please be more specific.

Answer (score 0):

For a generic class (with `<...>`)
use :

```
.*class\\s+(\\w+)(\\s+extends\\s+(\\w+))?(\\s+implements\\s+([\\w,\\s]+))?(<[\\w,\\s]+>)?\\s*\\{.*$
```